# When the transistor is working as a closed switch, is the collector current equal to the emitter current?

Tags: transistors

[image]

When the transistor is working as a closed switch like the one to the right in the attached figure, is \$I_{C}=I_{E}\$?

In other words, is \$I_{C}\$ gonna make it down to the ground?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collector current is slightly (to moderately) less than the emitter current, because the emitter current is the collector current **PLUS** the base current.

$$I_E = I_C + I_B$$

When a BJT is operated in *saturation*, as it is when used as a switch, the base current can be 10% (or more) of the emitter current.

When the BJT is not in saturation, the base current may be 0.5% of the emitter current (or even less).

Comment: I think this answer is more complete, than the accepted one. The deviation from \$I_C \approx I_E\$ as the transistor enters saturation may be the most important point that OP needs to be aware of, and is particularly apposite in the "transistor as a switch" scenario.